# Two Toast notifications for same app, at the same time. How is it prioritized and handled by the device?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, toast

I have an app which can(possibly) show two toast notifications to the user one after the other. I observed that if such scenario arises then only one of the two notifications is displayed to the user but once the user launches the app and then same notifications are presented to the user in message boxes and if he clicks "cancel" for the first message and then the next notification is presented. So, my doubt now is, If two toast notifications are there then how will the device handle it? and which of the two is displayed to the user? And in case only notification is presented to the user (by default behaviour of the device) then is there a way to display notifications one after the other?

This is similar to this  [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107988/if-two-local-notifications-have-the-same-fire-time-and-the-app-is-in-the-backgro)  but i want to know the behaviour of WP7 phones as the features of WP7 very different other smartphone OSes.

All suggestions, comments and answers are appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is this,

```
 public static void ShowToast()
    {
        try
        {
            string langKey = CacheManager.getInstance().getDataFromConfigFile(CacheManager.APP_CURRENT_LANGUAGE);
            string flag = CacheManager.getInstance().getDataFromConfigFile(CacheManager.APP_UPGRADE_STATUS);
            string catalogUpdateFlag = CacheManager.getInstance().getDataFromConfigFile(CacheManager.APP_CATALOG_UPGRADE_STATUS);

            CultureInfo ci;
            if ((null == langKey) || (langKey.Equals(Utils.LANGUAGE_EN)))
            {
                ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            }
            else
            {
                ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            }
            AppResources.Culture = ci;

            if (!Utils.isNullString(flag))
            {
                var toast = new ShellToast
                {
                    Title = AppResources.APP_NAME,
                    Content = getMessageStatus(flag),
                    NavigationUri = new System.Uri("/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative)
                };

                Logger.log(TAG, ":ShowToast():MessageToUser" + AppResources.APP_NAME + getMessageStatus(flag));


                toast.Show();
            }
            if (!Utils.isNullString(catalogUpdateFlag))
            {
                var toast = new ShellToast
                {
                    Title = AppResources.APP_NAME,
                    Content = getMessageStatus(catalogUpdateFlag),
                    NavigationUri = new System.Uri("/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative)
                };

                Logger.log(TAG, ":ShowToast():MessageToUser" + AppResources.APP_NAME + getMessageStatus(catalogUpdateFlag));


                toast.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.log(TAG, "Exception in ShowToast: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);

        }
    }
    private static string getMessageStatus(string flagType)
    {
        //string flag = CacheManager.getInstance().getApplicationSettings(CacheManager.APP_UPGRADE_STATUS);
        string flag = CacheManager.getInstance().getDataFromConfigFile(CacheManager.APP_UPGRADE_STATUS);
        string catalogUpdateFlag = CacheManager.getInstance().getDataFromConfigFile(CacheManager.APP_CATALOG_UPGRADE_STATUS);

        if (flagType == flag)
        {
            if (flag.Equals(CacheManager.MAJOR_UPGRADE))
            {
                return AppResources.APP_UPGRADE_CONFIRM;
            }

            else if (flag.Equals(CacheManager.MINOR_UPGRADE))
            {
                return AppResources.APP_UPGRADE_MINOR_CONFIRM;
            }
        }
        else if (flagType == catalogUpdateFlag)
        {
            return AppResources.APP_CATALOG_CONFIRM;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I have taken two different variables to know if its the application upgrade or just the catalogue upgrade(New items will be added to the existing ones). So if there is catalogue upgrade and/or application upgrade user will be notified.

Comment: Awesome. Code looks good to me, glad it is giving both messages back to back!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 has the potential to show both the messages, and which one first depends on which one the phone receives first.

If you look at the diagram on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558(v=vs.92).aspx you see that there is a lot of communication in sending a push (toast, tile or raw) notification. And it depends on the Microsoft Push Notification Service which normally sends it first come first serve.

So from the sounds of it, I would look into trying to limit how your application sends the toast notifications. So check if a toast notification has been sent to the phone within a certain amount of time, if so hold of on sending the next one in till that time has past.

Also remember to check if the MPNS actually sent the push notification to the, that will help in determining if the phone might have received the notification

In that link I post it goes into a lot of details about sending and receiving the push notifications.

Comment: That is the problem, both the notifications are coming back to back. So its picking only one of them. I will check the link, Thnx for the quick reply!

Comment: If the notifications are being sent back to back, why can't you make them into 1 toast instead of 2? If you check out the Sending Push notifications link at the bottom of the link I set you (or here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202945(v=vs.92).aspx) Check out the Toast Notification Payload section and you can set the priority of when the toast notification can be delivered.

Comment: Actually i fixed it in a different way and it works fine. I get notifications back to back to.. I will post the code tmrw :) thnx for all the help. Your answer really helped in a way.

Comment: Awesome, I am glad I was able to help in a way. Good luck!